# Spring Controller not returning a html page after an Ajax get Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

So I have a "discount" html page, where a user is prompted to enter a promo code, by using an Ajax GET request from the buttons OnClick, I am able to transfer this promo code to my spring controller, where I manipulate the data appropriately.

For some reason I am unable to "return" a new page from this controller, I do not get any noticeable errors on my server side but on my client side I get this error:

I am not sure if this is related or relevant.

I was wondering is my logic behind this flawed or am I not implementing the correct syntax to return a new page after the AJAX call.

Note: The AJAX request works fine as I am able to get a system.out.print to the console at the bottom of the controller with the relevant info. that I passed.

Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction(){


        var code = document.getElementById("code").value;
         var price = document.getElementById("price").value;

    $.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/calculateDiscount",
  data: {  
          code: code
    }, // parameters

    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
datatype: 'json'
//alert(status);
});
}

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div>
<center>

    <h3>Total Price: $<text th:text="${totalPrice}" id="price"/> </h3>
    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="code">
   <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate Discount</button> 


       <a style="color:blue" th:href="@{/welcome}">HomeScreen!</a>
       <br />                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    

<!--       <a style="color:blue" th:if="${myteam != null}" th:href="@{/leaveteam/{id}(id=${myteam?.id})}">Leave Team?!</a>
 -->
</center>       
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/calculateDiscount", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String CalculateDiscount(Model model, @RequestParam("code") String code,  RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

    ///need to calculate price if codes correct then return page with card info then after proceed call purchasebooks controller!
    System.out.println("Price: " + code );
     Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
     String email = loggedInUser.getName();

     UserLogin user = uR.findByUserName(email);

     int totalPrice = 0;
    if (code.equals("Discount1010"))
    { 
           Set<Book> books = user.getBooks();  
           for (Book b : books)
           {
               totalPrice = totalPrice + b.getPrice();
           }
           int discountPrice = (int) (totalPrice * .80);

           model.addAttribute("totalPrice", totalPrice);

            System.out.println("Price: " + discountPrice );
    }

    else {

        Set<Book> books = user.getBooks();

           for (Book b : books)
           {
               totalPrice = totalPrice + b.getPrice();
           }       
    System.out.println("Price: " + totalPrice );
    model.addAttribute("totalPrice", totalPrice);
    }

        return "payment";

}
```

The page I am trying to return:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Total Price: $<text th:text="${totalPrice}" id="price"/> </h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Any more info needed let me know.

K.

EDIT: In response to one of the answers below, I do have csrf disabled.
Here is my WebSecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
       UserLoginRepository userLoginRepository;

    //http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/registeruser").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")

     @Autowired
     DataSource dataSource;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home", "/registeruser").permitAll().antMatchers("/admin").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().logout()
                    .permitAll();
            http.exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
            http.csrf().disable();
            //disable csrf to allow communication (we also dont need for this fyp as its not live)
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/fonts/**", "/images/**", "/css/**");
        }



    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


           auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
          .usersByUsernameQuery("select user_name,password,user_status from user_login where user_name=?")
         .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select user_name, password from user_login where user_name=?");          


}

    @Bean
    public static NoOpPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
     return (NoOpPasswordEncoder) NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    }
```

Update: @ResponseBody annotation was added to the controller method, problem still persists

Comment: `500` represents that there is  a server side exception and it should have some logs,have you configured `log4j`?

Comment: @lucumt I updated my code just there, I am not receiving any 500 error. That was from a previous error I had. But no I have not implemented log4j

Comment: you ajax type is `json` and your controller return type is string,you need to keep them the same

Comment: @lucumt I changed the return types on both controller and ajax to be the same, still getting the same outcome

Comment: remove datatype and contentType of ajax and have a try

Comment: @lucumt same result!

Comment: When ajax call is submitted , spring method require to annotate with @ResponseBody annotation.

Comment: @SanjayPatel code updated to include this annotation, still the same result!

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is [CSRF](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html) problem. You have Spring Security implemented (I can see 
`SecurityContexHolder` class) and probably csrf enabled - this is default setting. If you want to disable it just use this

Java configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable();
}
```

XML:

```
<http>
    <!-- ... -->
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

But if you want to keep csrf enabled, you need to pass csrf token to ajax header. To do this, include csrf to meta tag:

```
<head>
    <meta name="_csrf" th:content="${_csrf.token}"/>
    <meta name="_csrf_header" th:content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

And then include csrf to Ajax request:

```
var token = /*[[${_csrf.token}]]*/ '';
var header = /*[[${_csrf.headerName}]]*/ '';

$(document).ajaxSend(function(e,xhr,options) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
```

Comment: I have updated my question with the websecurityclass that you are referring to, which already disables csrf.